# What are the various ways to skip a song on youtube on 3rd generation Apple TV using the iOS remote app or Apple Watch remote app

Tags: iphone, appletv, apple-watch, remote.app

What are the various ways to skip a song on youtube on Apple TV using the iOS remote app or Apple Watch remote app?

Currently, it seems like the easiest way to do this is to just fast forward till the end of the song.

What are the gestures on iPhone to skip a song and how can I do this on my Apple Watch?

Answer (score 1):

**On iPhone**

If a song is playing then go to details and you can press the two arrows at the bottom to fast forward/skip a song or you can tap the 10 icons to skip back or forward 10 seconds:

[image: buttons]

From [this Apple Support article:](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204989)

> Fast-forward: Tap the 10 icon to skip ten seconds ahead in a video. Or tap Fast forward
>
> to fast-forward in a song.
>
> Rewind: Tap the 10 icon to skip ten seconds back in a video. Or tap
>   Rewind to rewind in a song.

**On the Apple Watch**

Tap the two arrows to skip/fast-forward or rewind the song:

[image: watch]

From [this Apple Support article:](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT205549)

> To play or pause your music, or to go to the previous or next track, use the controls in Remote.

Comment: I'm not seeing this when in the youtube app on both apple watch and iPhone app. Maybe I should have mentioned I have 3rd generation apple tv

Comment: @user1898829 i also have a third generation apple tv... try making sure your app is on the latest version

Comment: my iPhone remote app is on the latest. but it looks different to the images you posted. What about the 10-second buttons I don't see that in your image?

Comment: see https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT205549